# How can I activate Profile in Spring Boot YAML?

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, spring-profiles

I have below application YAML of my Spring Boot (2.4.5) application with two profiles.

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
```

---

```
spring:
  profiles: prod
```

Now when I pass the arguments -Dspring.profiles.active=dev, it actually doesn't pickup the profile. Is there any changes in profile has been made recently.

When I activate the profile, like below it works

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

But as per the env profile can be different. I don't want to hard code the profile

Answer (score 4):

You should use the following instead in your application.yml:

```
spring
   config:
      activate:
         on-profile: dev

---
    
spring
   config:
      activate:
         on-profile: prod
```